# Fixed Position f

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hi I'm new in react native. I would like to ask how to fixed the position of these three colors, because every time i tried to click the search text input and the keyboard goes up those three colors will also goes up. I tried `position: 'fixed'` but it didnt work.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYgt1.png)

Here is also the code:

```
render(){
    return(
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
       <View style={{flex: 3, backgroundColor: '#E1F1FE'}}>
          <View style={styles.form}>
              <TextInput
              style={styles.input}
              placeholder = "Search"
              returnKeyType="go"
              underlineColorAndroid={'rgba(0,0,0,0)'}
              />
              <Icon name="search" size={20} color="#900" style={styles.label} />
          </View>
       </View>

       <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#77D3F8'}}>

       </View>

       <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#AEEAF2'}}>

       </View>

       <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#39CFDE'}}>

       </View>

     </View>
    );
  }
```

and the styles

```
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

module.exports = StyleSheet.create({
  navBar: {
    backgroundColor: '#EAEAEC',
  },
  title: {
    color: '#rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65)',
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: '#rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45)',
  },
  style3:{
    fontSize: 35,
    color: '#fff',
    padding: 10,
    alignContent:'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  style2: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flex:1
  },
  buttonstyle: {
    flex: 1
  },
  form:{
    flexDirection: 'row',
        borderBottomWidth:1,
        borderColor: '#00BBD1',
    marginTop:80,
    marginRight: 40,
    marginLeft: 40,
    alignContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  input: {
    height: 40,
    borderWidth: 0,
    flex: 1
  },
  label:{
    alignContent:'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginRight: 10,
    color: '#00BBD1'
  },
});
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: show the screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not going to be stick to position when keyboard activated. You may need to use [keyboardavoidingview](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboardavoidingview.html) or another package like [react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view) So design may not disturb when keyboard activated.